# Problemas al guardar archivos tipo imagenes , xls, doc en IBM CLOUD OBJECT STORAGE

Tags: php, curl, cloud, ibm-bluemix

estoy realizando un api en php con CURL para recibir un archivo desde un formulario el cual lo coloca en el Cloud Object Store de IBM Cloud.

Todo bien con archivos pdf y txt, pero al enviar archivos de imagenes o office al descargarlos del bucket (directo de la consola de la cloud) estos quedan corruptos y no se pueden renderizar.

He cambiado CURL OPTS,  headers, mines types, etc.. y nada

¿Alguien a pasado por esto?, muchas gracias!

Esta es la función:

```
function setOjbect($file,$narr,$rand)
{

//Nombre del archivo
$nombre_archivo = $rand.$file[$narr]['name'];
$size = $file[$narr]['size'];
$mime = $file[$narr]['type'];

//Guarda archivo en .tmp
$vtemp = setObjectTMP($file,$narr,$rand);

//Asigna ruta .tmp   
$tmp = '.tmp/'.$nombre_archivo;

$cFile = new CURLFile($tmp, $mime, basename($tmp));

$data = array( "filedata" => $cFile, "filename" => $cFile->postname,"type=".$mime);

//SI SE CARGO DE FORMA EXITOSA EL TMP
if($vtemp == 1)
{
//Envia archivo a Cloud Object Storage        

        $url = "CLOUD URL";

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        $headers = array(
            "Authorization: bearer "MI TOKEN AUTH" ",
            "Content-type: ".$mime.""

        );

        $options = array(             
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST            => 'PUT',                     
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers

        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


//borramos archivo del directorio temporal
deleteOjbect($tmp);

$error = 0;

}
else
{
    $error = 1;
}



        return $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue darle la ruta real del archivo temporal:

Reemplazar:

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,

por:

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents($tmp),